# regex negative lookaround

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'm trying to do keyword matching using the following regular expression

`you.{0,50}(?<!not)\s?special`

on the following list of strings

```
to include:
youaresospecial
you are so special
you are pretty special
you are special
youarespecial
you are sospecial
you are very special
you are super special
you are special
you special
you aresospecial

to exclude:
youarenotspecial
you are not special
youarenotspecial
```

it matches all of the strings that I need to include, however it also highlights one of the strings that I would like to exclude ('you are not special')

have been testing this on https://regex101.com/r/KTsjn8/1

can someone point out why?

Comment: Share the link to your attempt at regex101

Comment: added the link in the post

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/KTsjn8/3 ?

Comment: thank you - would you be able to explain why my version didn't work?

Comment: Didn't the answers below help? Do you need any more help with this? All you need is something like `you(?!.{0,50}not\s?special).{0,50}special` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8o3RS0/1)) and the reason why your regex fails is *backtracking*.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not work because `\s?` allows the pattern to match a zero-width position behind `special` and then successfully assert at that position that there is no `not` behind it with `(?<!not)`.

You would have to make two negative lookbehind assertions instead, one with a space, and one without:

```
you.{0,50}(?<!not\s)(?<!not)special
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/KTsjn8/2

Answer (score 0):

To explain why your regex fails:

Take `you are not special`.

- `you.{0,50}` matches `you are not`  (note the space)
- `(?<!not)` matches because `not`  is not `not`
- `\s?` matches because it's optional
- `special` matches.

To fix this, you can use a negative lookahead instead:

```
you(?!.*not\s?special).{0,50}special
```